# How do i make my character move in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a 3d fps game.
I'm using Unity Game Engine for the game

I want to add basic movement functionality like:

1. Keyboard movement
2. Mouse Movement

**So how do I add it?**

Comment: Have you considered doing the tutorials? https://learn.unity.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following code for keyboard movement

   ```
     float zMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * playerSpeed;
     float xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed;
     zMovement *= Time.deltaTime;
     xMovement *= Time.deltaTime;
     this.transform.Translate(0, 0, zMovement);
     this.transform.Translate(xMovement, 0, 0);
   ```

**Make sure to link this script with your player**

2. Add the following code for Mouse Movement

   ```
    Vector2 mC = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));
    mD += mC;

    this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-mD.y, Vector3.right);
    myBody.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(mD.x, Vector3.up);
   ```

**For the mouse movement to work follow the steps below**

1. Add the main camera object under your player so it becomes its child.
2. Link the script above to the main camera.